# Use of unresolved identifier 'contentURL'

Tags: swift3, fbsdk, fbsdksharekit

I got this error:

```
shareButton.shareContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent(contentURL:contentURL,
contentTitle: "My Share Title", 
contentDescription: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", 
imageURL: imageURL, 
peopleIDs: ["1561082740838259"], 
placeID: "166793820034304", 
ref: "myRefId")
```

Comment: *Where does the second `contentURL` come from*? That's what the compiler wants to know?

Comment: I'm mentioned my total code below. kindly check once

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `contentURL` like `imageURL`:

```
let contentURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers") 
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = contentURL
...

let imageURL = NSURL(string: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/95/Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg/2880px-Facebook_Headquarters_Menlo_Park.jpg")
shareButton.shareContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent(contentURL:contentURL, contentTitle ...
```